# How can I scale a graphic to text width without framebox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, input

I have exported a diagram created with Dia to LaTeX PGF macro (.tex) and now I want to include it. I have found the code below. It works great but the framebox creates border around my image which I don't want.

How can I scale it to text width without a border around the image?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{\textbf{\LaTeXe font-consistent diagrams using Dia}}
\author{Munthu}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A minimal example}
You will notice that the fonts used in Figure \ref{fig:latex_dia_integration} are consistent with the document.
\begin{figure}[hb]
\begin{center}
\framebox[0.90\textwidth]{%
\input{dia_latex_block_diagrams.tex}
}
\end{center}
\caption[]{\label{fig:latex_dia_integration} A sample font-consistent figure
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just omit `\framebox[...]{...}`. And instead `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` use only `\centering` after `\begin{figure}[htb]`.

Comment: `\resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}{\input{dia_latex_block_diagrams}}`?

Comment: @Zarko How will that scale anything?

Comment: @cfr, `\framebox` doesn't  scale anything (as far as I know). If OP doesn't like to have frame around image, than it not to be used. For scaling (without to see picture) is one way as you suggest in your answer. However, I prefer to draw picture so, that it can be used without any scaling.

Comment: @Zarko OK. Thanks. I never use `\framebox`. So the OP thinks they need scaling, but really they don't ;).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package.

```
\begin{figure}[hb]
  \centering
  \resizebox{.9\textwidth}{!}{\input{dia_latex_block_diagrams}}
  \caption[]{\label{fig:latex_dia_integration} A sample font-consistent figure}
\end{figure}
```

Obviously this is untested as your example cannot be compiled.